# How to add a floor selector control or widget when displaying indoor floorplan with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, mapbox, indoor

I need to provide a Floor picker for showing different floorplan for a building. I am using OpenLayers 6, Mapbox in my GIS application.

I need something similar to the attached image [image: FloorplanSample]

Currently I am sending floorId from the textbox, but I need to make a floor picker for selecting the floorId.

```
public getFloorData(): void {
this.myService.floor.subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.building = data.building;
  this.floor = data.floor;
  this.showImageLayer();
  this.showVectorLayer();

});
```

}

Comment: See plugin [ol-ext: control bar](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/bar/map.control.bar.html) for floor menu selection construction.

Comment: @TomazicM I recieve an array of floorIds when I make a get request using buildingId. Using these floorIds Floor selector should be displayed on map. And on selecting the floor that floorId and buildingId is used to fetch vector data and the image of the floorplan.

Comment: With the help of mentioned plugin you construct control bar with buttons with floor numbers, where button with floor number sends desired request to display the floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For control bar and toggle buttons [ol-ext](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext) plugins [ol.control.Bar](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.control.Bar.html) and [ol.control.Toggle](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.control.Toggle.html) can be used.

Brief description of the steps taken in the example code below, where five randomly created polygons take the role of floor plans.

1. Five vector layers are created, each with it's own random polygon, created with turf.js `turf.randomPolygon` method.
2. Control bar that will contain other controls/buttons is created with ol-ext `ol.control.Button` method.
3. Five toggle buttons for polygon selection are created with ol-ext `ol.control.Toggle` method. Function, specified with `onToggle` option takes care of showing/hiding desired layer. Buttons are added to the control bar.
4. For unified look default zoom control is hidden and zoom control added to the control bar.
5. Some modifications are done to the CSS styles/classes to achieve desired look.

CSS section:

```
.ol-control.ol-bar.ol-bottom.ol-right {
  bottom: 1.5em
}
.zoom {
  margin-top: 12px !important;
}
```

JS section:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    zoom: 5,
    center: [270701, 6247637]
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})
  ],
  controls: ol.control.defaults({zoom: false}),
});

var polygonLayer = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var polygon = turf.randomPolygon(1, {bbox: [-2, 47, 7, 48]});
  polygonLayer[i] = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(polygon, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'}),
    }),
    visible: false
  });
  map.addLayer(polygonLayer[i]);
}

var mainBar = new ol.control.Bar({toggleOne: true});
mainBar.setPosition('bottom-right');
map.addControl(mainBar);

var selectedPolygon = null;
var polygonControl;
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  polygonControl = new ol.control.Toggle ({
    html: i + '',
    title: 'Select polygon ' + i,
    onToggle: function(isSelected) {
      if (selectedPolygon) {
        polygonLayer[selectedPolygon].setVisible(false);
        selectedPolygon = null;
      }
      if (isSelected) {
        selectedPolygon = this.get('polygonNo');
        polygonLayer[selectedPolygon].setVisible(true);
      }
    }
  });
  polygonControl.set('polygonNo', i);
  mainBar.addControl(polygonControl);
}
    
mainBar.addControl(new ol.control.Zoom({className: 'zoom'}));
```

Thats's how the result looks like when on of the polygons is selected:
[image]

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/2Lea5xyz/

Comment: GIS SE site has policy of one question per question. If you have a new question, please post it as a separate question.